# What does this autocorrelation plot show?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, seasonality, differencing

I'm working with this [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theadammurphy/h2o_articles/main/time_series/elecequip.csv) from [Forecasting: Principles and Practice 2nd Edition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/).

I've calculated the 12-month seasonal difference (middle) and the autocorrelation plot (right).

[image]

The autocorrelation plot clearly isn't a typical 'stationary' plot. But what does it show? On the one hand, I want to say the 12 Month plot is stationary (since the majority of values lie within the CI on the autocorrelation plot). But having such a continuous shape cannot be a good sign.

Has seasonal differencing removed seasonality but left it with a trend? Or has seasonal differencing been ineffective?

In general, what do autocorrelation plots with these clear continuous shapes tell us?

Full code to reproduce the plot (minus axis label stuff)

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

df = pd.read_csv('elecequip.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=['date'])
# 12 Month seasonal differencing
df['12month_diff'] = df['orders'].diff(periods=12)
month12 = df['12month_diff'].dropna()

# 1x3 plot
fix, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(14, 4))

axes[0].plot(df['orders'])
axes[1].plot(month12)

lags = len(month12) - 1
plot_acf(month12, ax=axes[2], lags=lags, alpha=0.05)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is telling me that there is still quite high autocorrelation. While maybe "most" points lie within the CI, there's still quite a feq at the beginning which are not in, and show immediate autocorrelation, so maybe try a differencing of lag 1, on it's own or additionally.

Comment: Ok that's good to know! Does the continuous shape mean anything?